# HTML flex and image stretching

Tags: html, image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">
    <img src="smiley.gif">
    <div class="div2">
        A<br>Smiley<br>Face
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the above code to create an outer `div` with `flex display` and in it to be an image and another `div` with a text right to it. Code works but the `image` seems to strech... How can I make the image keep its original size? Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is stretching because the default value of align-self is stretch. You need to change it to center or something else.

```
align-self: center
```

See it the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

Comment: Um, it goes in the middle this way, it keeps its size though. Do you know how can I still make it appear on the top? (10px left and 10px top)

Comment: Can you try replacing `align-self: center;` with `align-self: flex-start;`